# IntelliJ error: branch 'origin/HEAD' does not point at a commit, some refs could not be read

Tags: git, intellij-idea

As far as I can tell everything in my git local repository is fine. I can commit, push, pull, whatever I like.

However, when I view the details of a commit in the IntelliJ log, the `Contained in branches:`

```
Can not load branches due to error:
error: branch 'origin/HEAD' does not point at a commit 
error: some refs could not be read 
error: branch 'origin/HEAD' does not point at a commit 
error: some refs could not be read
```

What could have caused this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`origin/head` sounds like it refers to the default branch set in your remote origin repo. For example, when I do `git branch -a`, I see this show up in the list:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

You might be missing this reference in your local repo, or your local repo's reference might be out of date, if the default branch is changed in the remote, and the old default is deleted.

### Possible Solution

If this is indeed the cause of your IDE error, then you can manually correct it using `git symbolic-ref`:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/<default-branch>
```

Where `<default-branch>` is the branch that is default in your remote repo.

### Updated Solution

So git actually has a more convenient command that can be used to update a local repo's symbolic-ref to the default branch in a remote repo:

```bash
git remote set-head <remote> --auto

# Or shorter
git remote set-head <remote> -a
```

- [Documentation for `git remote set-head`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

It was introduced in [commit bc14fac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc14fac825d9728c311aaa9d0aecf4960d4a3103) for git 1.6.3 (May 2009).

> Sets or deletes the default branch (`$GIT_DIR/remotes/<name>/HEAD`) for
>   the named remote.
>   **Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch.**
>   For example, if the default branch for `origin` is set to `master`, then `origin` may be specified wherever you would normally specify `origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks. After that a restart of IntelliJ is all it still needed.